# Transaction API on Italian Action

Tags: transactions, actions-on-google

I'm developing an action in two languages: italian and english.
In the english version transaction works well but when I try the same intent in italian it doesn't work. The issue happens when the "actions_intent_TRANSACTION_DECISION" is fired.
This is the request sent by the action:

```
    {
  "responseId": "d259c8b8-0081-4fa6-a090-09b58452d2bb-425db6e2",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "2 caffè",
    "action": "showbreakfastlist-selectelement.showbreakfastlist-selectelement-custom",
    "parameters": {
      "drink": "caffè",
      "number": 2
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/request-breakfast-drink-followup",
        "lifespanCount": 2,
        "parameters": {
          "drink": "caffè",
          "drink.original": "caffè",
          "number": 2,
          "number.original": "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/actions_capability_media_response_audio",
        "parameters": {
          "drink": "caffè",
          "drink.original": "caffè",
          "number": 2,
          "number.original": "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output",
        "parameters": {
          "drink": "caffè",
          "drink.original": "caffè",
          "number": 2,
          "number.original": "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/actions_capability_account_linking",
        "parameters": {
          "drink": "caffè",
          "drink.original": "caffè",
          "number": 2,
          "number.original": "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output",
        "parameters": {
          "drink": "caffè",
          "drink.original": "caffè",
          "number": 2,
          "number.original": "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/google_assistant_input_type_voice",
        "parameters": {
          "drink": "caffè",
          "drink.original": "caffè",
          "number": 2,
          "number.original": "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/request-breakfast-datetime-followup",
        "lifespanCount": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "date-time": {
            "date_time": "2020-07-28T14:00:00+02:00"
          },
          "date-time.original": "domani alle 14",
          "time": "",
          "time.original": "",
          "date": "",
          "date.original": "",
          "drink": "caffè",
          "drink.original": "caffè",
          "number": 2,
          "number.original": "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/addbreakfastdatetime-followup",
        "lifespanCount": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "date-time": {
            "date_time": "2020-07-28T14:00:00+02:00"
          },
          "date-time.original": "domani alle 14",
          "time": "",
          "time.original": "",
          "date": "",
          "date.original": "",
          "drink": "caffè",
          "drink.original": "caffè",
          "number": 2,
          "number.original": "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/add_drink_breakfast",
        "lifespanCount": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "drink": "caffè",
          "drink.original": "caffè",
          "number": 2,
          "number.original": "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/_actions_on_google",
        "lifespanCount": 98,
        "parameters": {
          "data": "{\"logged\":false,\"userType\":\"FULL_USER_STORAGE\",\"selectedBreakfast\":{\"type\":\"colazione continentale\",\"number\":\"4\",\"date\":null,\"extra\":null,\"dateTime\":\"2020-07-28T14:00:00+02:00\"}}",
          "breakfast_type": "colazione continentale",
          "breakfast_type.original": "continentale",
          "number": 2,
          "number.original": "2",
          "date-time": {
            "date_time": "2020-07-28T14:00:00+02:00"
          },
          "date-time.original": "domani alle 14",
          "time": "",
          "time.original": "",
          "date": "",
          "date.original": "",
          "drink": "caffè",
          "drink.original": "caffè"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/add_breakfast_when",
        "parameters": {
          "date-time": {
            "date_time": "2020-07-28T14:00:00+02:00"
          },
          "date-time.original": "domani alle 14",
          "time": "",
          "time.original": "",
          "date": "",
          "date.original": "",
          "drink": "caffè",
          "drink.original": "caffè",
          "number": 2,
          "number.original": "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/__system_counters__",
        "parameters": {
          "no-input": 0,
          "no-match": 0,
          "drink": "caffè",
          "drink.original": "caffè",
          "number": 2,
          "number.original": "2"
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/intents/bf162712-6dc2-4235-a49e-febdc9bfa1ac",
      "displayName": "REQUEST - breakfast - drink"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "it"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "source": "google",
    "version": "2",
    "payload": {
      "user": {
        "locale": "it-IT",
        "lastSeen": "2020-07-27T08:18:06Z",
        "userStorage": "{\"data\":{\"room\":{\"_id\":\"5ef31c7db5874400241a9435\",\"number\":3,\"room\":\"Room three\"},\"hotel\":{\"name\":\"Jhon Wick\",\"structureMail\":\"testgate42@gmail.com\",\"contactMail\":\"testgate42@gmail.com\",\"id\":\"5ed524e82713d400241afddc\"}}}",
        "userVerificationStatus": "VERIFIED"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "conversationId": "ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo",
        "type": "ACTIVE",
        "conversationToken": "[\"add_drink_breakfast\",\"_actions_on_google\",\"addbreakfastdatetime-followup\",\"request-breakfast-datetime-followup\",\"add_breakfast_when\"]"
      },
      "inputs": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT",
          "rawInputs": [
            {
              "inputType": "VOICE",
              "query": "2 caffè"
            }
          ],
          "arguments": [
            {
              "name": "text",
              "rawText": "2 caffè",
              "textValue": "2 caffè"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "surface": {
        "capabilities": [
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.ACCOUNT_LINKING"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
          }
        ]
      },
      "isInSandbox": true,
      "availableSurfaces": [
        {
          "capabilities": [
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "requestType": "SIMULATOR"
    }
  },
  "session": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo"
}
```

and this is the response:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "systemIntent": {
        "intent": "actions.intent.TRANSACTION_DECISION",
        "data": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.transactions.v3.TransactionDecisionValueSpec",
          "orderOptions": {
            "requestDeliveryAddress": "false"
          },
          "order": {
            "merchantOrderId": "lb1k",
            "createTime": "2020-07-27T08:18:13.862Z",
            "lastUpdateTime": "2020-07-27T08:18:13.862Z",
            "userVisibleOrderId": "lb1k",
            "transactionMerchant": {
              "id": "https://voiceconcierge.heyvoice.io/",
              "name": "Jhon Wick"
            },
            "buyerInfo": {
              "email": "testgate42@gmail.com",
              "firstName": "Voice",
              "lastName": "Concierge",
              "displayName": "Jhon Wick"
            },
            "contents": {
              "lineItems": [
                {
                  "id": "8q92",
                  "name": "colazione continentale",
                  "description": "4 colazione continentale",
                  "reservation": {
                    "status": "PENDING",
                    "userVisibleStatusLabel": "Reservation is pending.",
                    "type": "RESERVATION_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED",
                    "reservationTime": {
                      "timeIso8601": "2020-07-28T14:00:00+02:00"
                    },
                    "partySize": "4",
                    "staffFacilitators": [
                      {
                        "name": "Breakfast"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "note": "extra: 2 caffè"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "outputContexts": [
    {
      "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/reserve_breakfast",
      "lifespanCount": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "projects/voiceconcierge-7bc94/agent/sessions/ABwppHGsT53MrEHkv9pV7QGJI2SJDiCqoiSQ3_ftAc5BnIJ6F39ibSJd4X-v5neenKwvU7bU0bauHVyAldsC1Wb_sRo/contexts/_actions_on_google",
      "lifespanCount": 99,
      "parameters": {
        "data": "{\"logged\":false,\"userType\":\"FULL_USER_STORAGE\",\"selectedBreakfast\":{\"type\":\"colazione continentale\",\"number\":\"4\",\"date\":null,\"extra\":{\"drink\":\"caffè\",\"number\":\"2\"},\"dateTime\":\"2020-07-28T14:00:00+02:00\"},\"BREAKFAST_UNIQUE_ORDER_ID\":\"lb1k\"}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

someone have any suggestion?

Comment: the error shown in the console is : MalformedResponse at expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0].input_value_data.option_value_spec.list_select: the number of 'items' must be between 2 and 30

Comment: I can't seem to find a `list_select` value in your posted JSON payloads. Is there anything notably different between the Italian and English payloads that you can identify?